# SimpleAdapter фильтр

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Всем привет!
Возникла необходимость использовать фильтрацию списка (поиск в списке по значению в поле name), построенном с помощью SimpleAdapter. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать и насколько возможно? Гугл оказался достаточно скуп на туториалы с использованием именно с помощью SimpleAdapter. В текущей реализации получается неверная фильтрация списка.

MainActivity class

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search here");    
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Adapter class

```
public class MyAdapterMain extends SimpleAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results;
    private Context context;


    public MyAdapterMain(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource,
                     String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.results = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = view;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_currencies_main, null);
        }
        TextView id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
        id.setText(results.get(position).get("id"));

        TextView symbol = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.symbol);
        symbol.setText(results.get(position).get("symbol"));

        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(results.get(position).get("name"));

        TextView price = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.price);
        price.setText(results.get(position).get("price"));

        TextView percent_change_1h = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.percent_change_1h);
        percent_change_1h.setText(results.get(position).get("percent_change_1h"));

        TextView percent_change_24h = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.percent_change_24h);
        percent_change_24h.setText(results.get(position).get("percent_change_24h"));

        TextView percent_change_7d = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.percent_change_7d);
        percent_change_7d.setText(results.get(position).get("percent_change_7d"));

        TextView imgLink = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgLink);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
        imgLink.setText(results.get(position).get("imgLink"));
        Picasso.with(context).load(results.get(position).get("imgLink")).into(img);

        return v;

    }
}
```

Comment: посмотрел подробнее Вашу реализацию, я не совсем понял, где сама фильтрация?

Comment: Фильтрация осталась от использования BaseAdapter в виде:adapter.getFilter().filter(newText); На данный момент она мягко скажем не фильтрует.

Comment: У `SimpleAdaptera` фильтр ищет соответствия в каждом слове всех значений по всем ключам `HashMap`. Можно переопределить метод `getFilter()` и возвращать свою реализацию фильтра, которую в свою очередь можно скопировать из сорцов адаптера и изменить под свои нужды.

Comment: А у вас случайно нет годной статьи на эту тему? Что за сорцы из адаптера? Искать по всем ключам в Hashmap как раз то, что нужно

Comment: Так он это и делает, что Вас тогда не устраивает? Сорцы - это код, посмотреть можно [здесь](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.java), например, или установить в SDK-Manager "Sources for Android" нужной версии и по F4 - будет открываться код любого класса из API прямо в студии. В самом низу класс `SimpleFilter` - его он и использует для фильтрации. Но мне кажется Вам будет проще сделать по примеру: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/831779/11515

Comment: А вообще-то он у Вас не фильтрует, потому что Вы берёте данные из своего не фильтрованного списка `results.get(position)`. Замените на `getItem(position)` - тогда данные будут браться из отфильтрованного внутреннего списка. Вы не правильно его используете - `SimpleAdapter` вполне законченный адаптер и работать с ним можно напрямую без наследования.

Comment: спасибо за советы!

Answer (score 2):

Не забудьте сделать адаптеру

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 1):

Доброй ночи. Позволите, я приведу свое решение.
Инициализируете поле поиска:

```
   <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

Создаете меню c единственным значением, которое будет использовано в заголовке:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_24dp"
        android:title="Поиск по людям.."
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:hint="Введите имя ил группу"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:letterSpacing="0.01"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10.1sp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_rectangle"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Далее в коде, имплиментируете интерфейс SearchView.OnQueryTextListener. И в переопределенных методах выполняете поиск.

```
class PeopleFragment : Fragment(), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
private lateinit var adapter: PeopleAdapter
private var allUsers: ArrayList<User> = ArrayList()
private var query: String = ""

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_people, container, false)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

private fun setupRecyclerView(users: ArrayList<User>){
    adapter = PeopleAdapter(context!!, users, object : ClickToProfile{
        override fun openProfile(user: User) {
            listener?.replaceFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance(user), true)
        }
    })
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    menu.clear()
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_people, menu)

    // Search setting
    val searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search)
    val searchView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem) as SearchView

    // set colors and hint text
    val searchAutoComplete = searchView.findViewById<SearchView.SearchAutoComplete>(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
    searchAutoComplete.setHintTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.disableColor))
    searchAutoComplete.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.textColor))
    searchAutoComplete.hint = "Поиск..."

    // Color for searchField background
    val searchPlate = searchView.findViewById<View>(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate)
    searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_white_rectangle)

    // set close image
    val searchCloseIcon = searchView.findViewById<ImageView>(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn)
    searchCloseIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp)

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.search -> {

        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean { return true }

override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {
    val filteredUsers = ArrayList<User>()

        if (query!!.isEmpty()) {
            filteredUsers.addAll(allUsers)

        } else {
            this.query = query.toLowerCase()

            for (user in allUsers) {
                val text = ( user.firstName + user.lastName +
                        user.userStatus + user.groupId).toLowerCase()

                if (text.contains(query))
                    filteredUsers.add(user)
            }
        }

        setupRecyclerView(filteredUsers)

    return true
}
```

}

[image: Выглядит поиск следующим образом]
Плюс данной реализации моментальный поиск. Не нажимая на кнопку поиск, просто изменяя запрос, данные сразу будут фильтроваться.

Нашел специально для Вас ссылку на репозиторий авторов https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView

Адаптер простой, и выглядит так:

```
class PeopleAdapter(context: Context, private var items: MutableList<User>, private var clickToProfile: ClickToProfile) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PeopleViewHolderItem>() {

private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: PeopleViewHolderItem, position: Int) {
    viewHolder.bindTo(items[position])
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PeopleViewHolderItem {
    return PeopleViewHolderItem.create(inflater, viewGroup, clickToProfile)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

fun addUser(user: User) {
    items.add(user)
    this.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

А он уже связан со viholder-ом) Его я если надо тоже добавлю, но в этом примере я использовался binding, можно обоййтись без него в котлине.

```
class PeopleViewHolderItem private constructor(private val binding: ItemPeopleBinding,
                                           private val clickToProfile: ClickToProfile) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
fun bindTo(user: User) {
    binding.avatar.setImageURI(user.avatar)
    binding.nameField.text = user.firstName + " " + user.lastName
    binding.groupIdField.text = user.groupId
    binding.peopleStatusField.text = user.userStatus

    // listener
    binding.moreBtn.setOnClickListener{ clickToProfile.openProfile(user) }
    binding.executePendingBindings()
}

companion object {
    fun create(inflater: LayoutInflater,
               parent: ViewGroup, clickToProfile: ClickToProfile): PeopleViewHolderItem {
        val binding = ItemPeopleBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        return PeopleViewHolderItem(binding, clickToProfile)
    }
}
```

Comment: четстно говоря написал, а теперь читаю Ваш вопрос, понимаю, что несколько не то писал. ночь сказалась.

Comment: а как у вас реализуется адаптер?

Comment: а адаптер совсем простой, поиск на стороне активити. После, адаптер пересоздается с новыми значениями. Сейчас добавлю

Comment: спасибо за хороший пример, буду продолжать искать реализацию для Simple adapter.