# Поиск элементов в Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

На разметке активности есть `ListView` и `EditText`. При вводе символов пользователем в ListView должны оставаться только объекты которые содержат введенные символы. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть интерфейс `Filterable`  но также можно написать свой метод

```
public void searchItem(String textToSearch){
        for(String item:items){
            if(!item.contains(textToSearch)){
                listItems.remove(item);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Если вам сложно то посмотрите тут пошагово повторите [list view поиск](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/)

А лучше всего забыть `ListView` и перейти на `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то делал с `Filterable` по [этому образцу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21972358), все получилось:

Адаптер:

```
public class vJournalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JournalModel> implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<JournalModel> items;
    private Context mContext;
}
```

И сам класс:

```
private class JournalFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        List<JournalModel> allJournals = getAllJournals();
        if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){

            result.values = allJournals;
            result.count = allJournals.size();
        }else{
            ArrayList<JournalModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<JournalModel>();
            for(JournalModel j: allJournals){
                if(j.source.title.contains(constraint))
                    filteredList.add(j);
            }
            result.values = filteredList;
            result.count = filteredList.size();
        }

        return result;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        if (results.count == 0) {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        } else {
            items = (ArrayList<JournalModel>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```